# rails 4, content_tag, pass in data-turbolinks-track?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, content-tag

What is the proer syntax to pass `data-turbolinks-track => 'reload'` to a `content_tag`?

I want to do this:

`content_tag(:link, nil, rel: rel, href: url_for(page: page != 1 ? page : nil, only_path: false), data-turbolinks-track => reload)`

But this is throwing an exception :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

`content_tag(:link, nil, rel: rel, href: url_for(page: page != 1 ? page : nil, only_path: false), data: {'turbolinks-track' => 'reload'})`

Creates:

`<link rel="next" href="http://hipyard.dev:3000/m/toronto-area-on?page=2" data-turbolinks-track="reload">`